# How can I convert my file name as a string variable to fit with typeof(filename)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, model-view-controller, edmx, typeof

I'm using a list of file names to produce a break down of the files structure. Using the file name I can get the list of field names using

```
var FieldNames = typeof(Carers).GetProperties().Select(f => f.Name).ToList();
```

However, if I replace 'Carers' with is obviously a Class with the string variable of the Class name it causes conflict with typeof(). How can I convert the string variable to work with typeof()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `typeof("type_name")` to get a `Type`. Instead you should use either:

```
Type.GetType("type_name").GetProper...
```

or

```
Assembly.GetType("type_name").GetProper...
```

In the first method, you may need to specify which Assembly the type belongs to (ref: [Type.GetType Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=netframework-4.8))

In the second method you would need to fetch whichever `Assembly` defined the type (ref: [Assembly.GetType Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.gettype?view=netframework-4.8))

In either case, they return a `Type` which you can use `GetProperties` on as you are in your existing code.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried it and got a System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error. I tried adding the namespace which resulted in the same error.

Comment: You may need to specify the fully qualified type name (including the namespace) rather than just `Carer`.  For example, `Namespace.Carer`

Comment: That worked, thank you. I put the project name and namespace before the table name and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think this should work:

> var FieldNames = Type.GetType("Carers").GetProperties().Select(f => f.Name).ToList();

Comment: Thank you Gerwin, this worked also providing you preceded the file name with project and namespace.